# relation not work although when test work but return nil

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have to model `ConversationStatistic`, `Conversation` . I need `Conversation` has_one `ConversationStatistic` .

`conversations tables`

```
  id 
  t.string "conversation_uid", null: false
  t.boolean "open"
  t.datetime "created_at", precision: 6, null: false
  t.datetime "updated_at", precision: 6, null: false
  t.integer "company_id", null: false
```

`conversation_messages tables`

```
  id 
  t.string "conversation_uid"
  t.jsonb "messages"
  t.integer "count_conversations_parts"
  t.datetime "created_at", precision: 6, null: false
  t.datetime "updated_at", precision: 6, null: false
```

```
class ConversationMessage < ApplicationRecord
  # validates of conversation_uid must exist & unique
  validates :conversation_uid, presence: true, uniqueness: true
  # # relations
  belongs_to :conversation, foreign_key: :conversation_uid
end
```

```
class Conversation < ApplicationRecord

  # validates of conversation_uid must exist & unique
  validates :conversation_uid, presence: true, uniqueness: true
  # validates of intercom_key must exist & unique
  validates :contact_uid, presence: true

  has_one :conversation_message, foreign_key: :conversation_uid
end
```

when test in rails console `Conversation.last.conversation_message` return nil although `conversation_uid` in `Conversation` exist in `conversation_message`

Comment: Your question is not clear. Please provide more context on what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: If I am understanding your question correctly, you still have to actually create conversation_message instances, and assign them to a conversation. Just defining the relationship in the model will not create anything automatically

Comment: @johansenja please more information

Comment: in the console: `c = Conversation.create; cm = ConversationMessage.create(conversation: c); puts c.conversation_message` - or you can even use the rails-provided helper `c.create_conversation_message`

Answer (score 0):

I stacked with the same error:
To resolve this you can try to pass class_name argument to the belong_to relation

try to use this:

```
belongs_to :conversation, foreign_key: :conversation_uid, class_name: 'Conversation'
```

also you can try to add class_name to has_one associaton

P.S. Don't forget to add the uniq index for the `conversation_uid`

Answer (score 0):

If you expect something like this

> Conversation.last.conversation_message **should return record** if  `conversation_uid` of last conversation exists in `conversation_messages` table

Then you need to make set "primary_key" to `conversation_uid` on `Conversation`.

```
class Conversation < ApplicationRecord
  has_one :conversation_message, foreign_key: :conversation_uid,
                                 primary_key: :conversation_uid
end
```

Comment: Why can't  create `conversation_message` ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid (Validation failed: Conversation must exist)

Answer (score 0):

Unless I am missing something but I believe if you have declared relationship between models properly then there will be no need to validate presence of `uid` because no conversation_message will exist without a conversation unless you explicitly indicate that by adding `belongs_to :conversation, optional: true` to your model. To get a record using `Conversation.last.conversation_message` then you have to do this when creating a `conversation_message`

```
def create
  @conversation = Conversation.find(params[:conversation_id])
  @conversation.create_conversation_message(conversation_message_params)
end
```

With this, `@conversation.conversation_message` should return a record